# Norm of weakly convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space with associated norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$, and $(x_n)_{n≥1}$ is a sequence in $H$ and $x\in H$.
I have tried with choosing the orthonormal basis $e_n$ and showing that this converges weakly to $0$, but that the norm doesn't. Can someone help me with how to show this.

Comment: Weak convergence to 0 follows from Bessel.

Answer (score 0):

It does not follow ! We have

$$(1) \quad x_n \to x$$

weakly. Now assume that

$$(2) \quad ||x_n|| \to ||x||.$$

Then (1) and (2) imply that $||x_n -x|| \to 0,$ a contradiction.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Here can you find a proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)

Answer (score 0):

An example: let $H=\ell^2$ and $(u_n)$ the usual orthonormal basis of $H$.

Then show that $u_n \to 0$ weakly. But $ ||u_n||=1 \to 1.$